# gitlab-runner, stuck jobs in creating mode (500 internal server error)

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem that I can not solve alone.
I spent the day on it and I tried to find a solution by myself before creating this ticket.

**Context:**

- I use the latest version of Gitlab proposed: `sameersbn / gitlab: 11.5.1`
- I have a runner launched into a docker container: `gitlab / gitlab-runner: alpine`
- I use [Traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik)

Everything is started thanks to docker-compose.

**Steps:**

1. I launch all of my containers
2. I record a runner (command visible below)
3. I notice in the admin that my runners are well recorded in the gitlab: `/ admin / runners`

[image: recorded]

4. I run a pipeline, and the job is blocked: /

[image: Job is blocked]

[image: Job is blocked]

I have tried everything:
  - update the gitlab
  - update the runner and use a previous version
  - remove the runner from the gitlab network
  - ...

**Details:**

My Traefik `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:alpine
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /data/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - /data/traefik/acme:/etc/traefik/acme
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: portainer
    networks:
      - traefik
    labels: 
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.backend=portainer"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

My Gitlab docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:4.0.9-1
    container_name: gitlab-redis
    command:
      - --loglevel warning
    networks:
      - gitlab
    volumes:
      - /data/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis:Z
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"

  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:10
    container_name: gitlab-postgresql
    networks:
      - gitlab
    volumes:
      - /data/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:Z
    environment:
      - DB_USER=gitlab
      - DB_PASS=password
      - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
      - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"

  registry:
    image: registry:2
    container_name: gitlab-registry
    restart: always
    expose:
        - "5000"
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - gitlab
      - traefik
    volumes:
        - /data/gitlab/registry:/registry
        - /data/gitlab/certs:/certs
    labels:
      - traefik.port=5000
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:registry.mydomain.com
      - traefik.frontend.auth.basic=mydomain:fd9ef338f7de0f196c5409a668102b9a
    environment:
        - REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL=error
        - REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/registry
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM=https://gitlab.mydomain.com/jwt/auth
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE=container_registry
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER=gitlab-issuer
        - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE=/certs/registry.crt
        - REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
    networks:
      - gitlab
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /data/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner:Z
    environment:
      - CI_SERVER_URL=https://gitlab.mydomain.com/
      - REGISTRATION_TOKEN=FzZtgyN1cAMzoYne89ts
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"

  gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:11.5.1
    container_name: gitlab-ce
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgresql
      - registry
    ports:
      - "10080:80"
      - "10022:22"
    networks:
      - gitlab
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - /data/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data:Z
      - /data/gitlab/certs:/certs
    environment:
      - DEBUG=false

      - DB_ADAPTER=postgresql
      - DB_HOST=postgresql
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_USER=gitlab
      - DB_PASS=password
      - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production

      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379

      - TZ=Europe/Paris
      - GITLAB_TIMEZONE=Paris

      - GITLAB_HTTPS=true
      - SSL_SELF_SIGNED=false

      - GITLAB_HOST=gitlab.mydomain.com
      - GITLAB_PORT=
      - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022
      - GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=w58HODDUerP7YOuAbt9heD9j6s80P5A8POUdsd4wHeh7tLU8wdSG0noq2LsRnvqsff9btHJDovejeTMWflg78tvKqT7y9omqVTvh
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=w58HODDUerP7YOuAbt9heD9j6s80P5A8POUdsd4wHeh7tLU8wdSG0noq2LsRnvqsff9btHJDovejeTMWflg78tvKqT7y9omqVTvh
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=w58HODDUerP7YOuAbt9heD9j6s80P5A8POUdsd4wHeh7tLU8wdSG0noq2LsRnvqsff9btHJDovejeTMWflg78tvKqT7y9omqVTvh

      - GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - GITLAB_ROOT_EMAIL=

      - GITLAB_NOTIFY_ON_BROKEN_BUILDS=true
      - GITLAB_NOTIFY_PUSHER=false

      - GITLAB_EMAIL=notifications@example.com
      - GITLAB_EMAIL_REPLY_TO=noreply@example.com
      - GITLAB_INCOMING_EMAIL_ADDRESS=reply@example.com

      - GITLAB_BACKUP_SCHEDULE=daily
      - GITLAB_BACKUP_TIME=01:00

      - SMTP_ENABLED=false
      - SMTP_DOMAIN=www.example.com
      - SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - SMTP_PORT=587
      - SMTP_USER=mailer@example.com
      - SMTP_PASS=password
      - SMTP_STARTTLS=true
      - SMTP_AUTHENTICATION=login

      - IMAP_ENABLED=false
      - IMAP_HOST=imap.gmail.com
      - IMAP_PORT=993
      - IMAP_USER=mailer@example.com
      - IMAP_PASS=password
      - IMAP_SSL=true
      - IMAP_STARTTLS=false

      - OAUTH_ENABLED=false
      - OAUTH_AUTO_SIGN_IN_WITH_PROVIDER=
      - OAUTH_ALLOW_SSO=
      - OAUTH_BLOCK_AUTO_CREATED_USERS=true
      - OAUTH_AUTO_LINK_LDAP_USER=false
      - OAUTH_AUTO_LINK_SAML_USER=false
      - OAUTH_EXTERNAL_PROVIDERS=

      - OAUTH_CAS3_LABEL=cas3
      - OAUTH_CAS3_SERVER=
      - OAUTH_CAS3_DISABLE_SSL_VERIFICATION=false
      - OAUTH_CAS3_LOGIN_URL=/cas/login
      - OAUTH_CAS3_VALIDATE_URL=/cas/p3/serviceValidate
      - OAUTH_CAS3_LOGOUT_URL=/cas/logout

      - OAUTH_GOOGLE_API_KEY=
      - OAUTH_GOOGLE_APP_SECRET=
      - OAUTH_GOOGLE_RESTRICT_DOMAIN=

      - OAUTH_FACEBOOK_API_KEY=
      - OAUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=

      - OAUTH_TWITTER_API_KEY=
      - OAUTH_TWITTER_APP_SECRET=

      - OAUTH_GITHUB_API_KEY=
      - OAUTH_GITHUB_APP_SECRET=
      - OAUTH_GITHUB_URL=
      - OAUTH_GITHUB_VERIFY_SSL=

      - OAUTH_GITLAB_API_KEY=
      - OAUTH_GITLAB_APP_SECRET=

      - OAUTH_BITBUCKET_API_KEY=
      - OAUTH_BITBUCKET_APP_SECRET=

      - OAUTH_SAML_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE_URL=
      - OAUTH_SAML_IDP_CERT_FINGERPRINT=
      - OAUTH_SAML_IDP_SSO_TARGET_URL=
      - OAUTH_SAML_ISSUER=
      - OAUTH_SAML_LABEL="Our SAML Provider"
      - OAUTH_SAML_NAME_IDENTIFIER_FORMAT=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
      - OAUTH_SAML_GROUPS_ATTRIBUTE=
      - OAUTH_SAML_EXTERNAL_GROUPS=
      - OAUTH_SAML_ATTRIBUTE_STATEMENTS_EMAIL=
      - OAUTH_SAML_ATTRIBUTE_STATEMENTS_NAME=
      - OAUTH_SAML_ATTRIBUTE_STATEMENTS_FIRST_NAME=
      - OAUTH_SAML_ATTRIBUTE_STATEMENTS_LAST_NAME=

      - OAUTH_CROWD_SERVER_URL=
      - OAUTH_CROWD_APP_NAME=
      - OAUTH_CROWD_APP_PASSWORD=

      - OAUTH_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=
      - OAUTH_AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=
      - OAUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN=

      - OAUTH_AZURE_API_KEY=
      - OAUTH_AZURE_API_SECRET=
      - OAUTH_AZURE_TENANT_ID=

      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_ENABLED=true
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_HOST=registry.mydomain.com
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_API_URL=http://localhost:5000
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_KEY_PATH=/certs/registry.key
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_ISSUER=gitlab-issuer
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:gitlab.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.backend=gitlab"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"

networks:
  gitlab:
    driver: bridge
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

Command for register my runner:

```
docker exec -it gitlab-runner gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --name "Doker runner dind 1" \
  --url "https://gitlab.mydomain.com/" \
  --registration-token "FzZtgyN1cAMzoYne89ts" \
  --env "COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/cache" \
  --env "GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true" \
  --env "DOCKER_DRIVER=overlay2" \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image docker:stable-dind \
  --docker-privileged="true" \
  --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --docker-volumes /cache \
  --tag-list "docker,dind" \
  --run-untagged \
  --locked="false"
```

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago, IIRC you need to check either your workhorse or your gitaly logs and compare them to the runner logs. Basically you should see a similar message appear each log at the same time. I aslo spent a day on it and found it was a configuration issue. If you're lucky a I wrote down the fix somewhere; if I'm lucky I'll find them and post my notes on the issue in a bit..

Comment: Sorry for my late response.

I have long investigated, without success: /
So I started to put me a gitlab with the native Docker image of gitlab, and it works today!

If it interests someone I can provide my docker-composer.yml with traefik, portainer, a listener of the change of the certificates let's encrypt which automatically exports the .crt and .key to bind them to the gitlab and the registry, a docker registry, gitlab-ce and a runner

Thanks anyway for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

According to my notes a `500` appearing in the `Gitlab-Runner` doesn't indicate much. It simply echoes the error it receives from `workhorse` which mangles the real message, some variant of `4XX` from either `gitaly` or `linguist` into a `500`. The first log to check is ones `production.log` but this seems to only log the `500` errors emitted by `workhorse`, so you have to got a level deeper and scan your `workhorse.log`.

#### Gitaly

Check the `workhorse.log` for a version mismatch between `gitaly` and `workhorse`. As I recall it was critical that both applications have comparable version numbers, there was a table one could check, as this dictated which protocols they understood.

#### Linguist

This was a really obscure issue I encountered. Essentially the version of Ruby used to run `Gitaly` and the version of Ruby used by `Gitaly` to run `gitaly-ruby`, the sub-processes it spawns internally, were different. This is apparently indicated by the cryptic messages

```
time="2017-12-04T18:11:34+02:00" level=fatal msg="load config" config_path=/etc/gitaly/config.toml error="load linguist colors: exit status 1; stderr: \"/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs': Your bundle is locked to rake (12.1.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (12.1.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (12.1.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound)\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'\\n\\tfrom /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'\\n\""
time="2017-12-04T18:17:54+02:00" level=info msg="Starting Gitaly" version="Gitaly, version 0.52.0, built 20171204.135804"
```

#### Note :

**Please bear in mind that my notes are particular to Gentoo, a different version of `GitlabHQ` and may or may not be applicable to your situation accordingly. Please update your question as you find out more information since my notes may have further information that is relevant to your problem**